# Enable backdrop in offcanvas

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

To open an offcanvas panel, I have added `show` to its class (without show it won't open). However, now `backdrop` is not working, and clicking outside the panel won't close it.
Is there anyway to open the panel without using `show` or have `backdrop` behavior alongside `show`? Thank you in advance.

Here is my .html file:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end show" data-bs-backdrop="true">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title">
            panel
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" (click)="close()"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have included the `js` and `css` files from [`bootstrap getting started`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

[Offcanvas docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#placement)

Working stackblitz for reference

#### Full Code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight">Toggle right offcanvas</button>

    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel">Offcanvas right</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cr8rjw)

Comment: Thanks @naren-murali, something I've not mentioned in my question (I didn't know it makes such a difference) is that the panel is opened by clicking on a context menu item. I used the button in your example, and it worked without need to add js and css files. But I cannt add a button, therefore, I used a very customized workaround to solve it ...